# Improving accuracy of address returned by Google Maps using reverse geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

We are using mobile application to track the location of the users. we have done testing of the application and found that the accuracy of the address is not correct most of the time. while testing we have also found that multiple users on the same location getting different addresses from google which is sometimes 1km away from their actual locations.

we are using reverse geocoding to get the address of the user. mobile application sends the latitude and longitude to server. server makes the reverse geocoding api call to the google and fetch the address from the google.

I want to know what we can do to improve the accuracy of the results returned by google using reverse geocoding?

Comment: Can you give an example? Maybe a lat/long that doesn't return an address you expect? That might help us determine what is incorrect and why.